# ActionBar not being created even with min SDK version set to 11

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I have my min SDK version set to 11 and my target SDK version set to 11. I have an activity with some fragments in it. The style has `parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"` and doesn't hide the actionbar. In the activity where I expect to see the actionbar, I have an override of `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. My understanding is that onCreateOptionsMenu() will automatically be called when the activity starts and that will create the actionbar. This is not happening for me. I'm not sure if my understanding is wrong or if I'm doing something wrong that is causing it not to show up.

To be clear, my onCreateOptionsMenu method is not even firing. I suspect the problem is in another part of the code, but I don't know what it could be.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.signin_layout_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Here is my menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_signin_layout"
         android:title="stuff"
         android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

Here is the style that activity is using:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <!-- Window attributes -->
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">36dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/WindowTitle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>

    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.Button</item>

    <!-- Button styles -->
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Widget.Button</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your theme needs to be `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` for the actionbar to show.

Comment: yes a Holo theme is needed, see [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you inflating the menu and returning "true", to indicate that you've handle the action, correctly in your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` override? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#Inflating

If you're returning false, the event will bubble up to the parent, which by default does nothing.

Comment: Yeah, I'll update the question with my onCreateOptionsMenu() method.

Comment: What's the menu XML look like? Are you getting an inflation error, perhaps?

Comment: I've added the XML for the menu. I'm not getting any exceptions.

Comment: Have you tried setting an @null (or some other icon, just to test) into the android:drawable? Since it's expecting a drawable image for the action bar, I wonder if that's preventing it from showing? That would be since you have the "withText" option in the showAsAction attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work. The onCreateOptionsMenu() method is never called. I'm now pretty sure my problem must be elsewhere. I'll add the Activity style to the original question, maybe I'm doing something wrong there.

Comment: A title bar is showing up. Perhaps that's why the action bar is not showing.

Comment: It appears the problem might have been the style. I changed it to `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` and now I'm getting the error `You cannot combine custom title with other title features`